# localhost vai direto para os projetos

Tags: wamp

[image: Quando abro meu localhost, nao aparece mas aquela tela inicial de habito do localhost, e sim que eu vou direto pro meu diretório www, alguém sabe o porque?]

Quando abro meu localhost, nao aparece mas aquela tela inicial de habito do localhost, e sim que eu vou direto pro meu diretório www, alguém sabe o porque?

Comment: Provavelmente o arquivo index.php do www foi apagado.

Comment: Verifique se na sua pasta `www` tem o arquivo `index.php`, caso tiver, deve ser alguma configuração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clinton, Aconselho reinstalar o [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) para que os arquivos originais voltem e o problema seja resolvido.

Answer (score 3):

Baixe aqui o index.php do Wamp avulso.

http://downloads.jlbn.net/wampindex.html